# Asp Net Core web API - How to send image and JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I send two parameters in one request?
I know how to send one request with one parameter.

I use `postman` to send the requests.
This is the `person` code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(List<IFormFile> files, Person person)
```

How can I realize this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that holds both parameters.

```
public class AddRequest
{
   public Person Person {get; set;}
   public List<IFormFile> Files {get; set;}
}
```

then change your controller to accept the wrapper class

```
 [HttpPost("Add")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Add(AddRequest request)
```

then just create an instance of the AddRequest class, populate it with your parameters, and POST it to the 'Add' endpoint

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: how i can post from client side ? i dont have idea

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending **multipart/form-data** from front-end then you can receive it like as

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Person person)
{
   var files = Request.Form.Files;

   //your code here

}
```

I hope it will fill your requirement